# Group_photo telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я написал тг бота на Python на библиотеке Telebot. Как мне можно отследить, что пользователь отправляет не одну фотографию а Group_photo, и переслать эти фотографии одним сообщением?